# Provide file in git but ignore all changes

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to

- provide an initial version of the file in git,
- and ignore all future changes

But using `.gitignore` does not seems to work for me, as the file *will* show up as modified in `git status`, even listed in `.gitignore`, once tracked in git.

Is it possible?

Comment: @ObsidianAge, thx, will `git rm --cached` keep the file for people to do the initial clone?

Comment: @PhilRoss, will `git update-index --assume-unchanged` prevent it from appearing as modified in the ***future***? That answer was not clear.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, thx, the help there is helpful, but that's not what I'm asking -- "_If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git_" -- I _need_ to change the file, yet tell git to forget it at the same time.